# Как с помощью seaborn можно отобразить значения DataFrame в виде заштрихованной таблицы? (seaborn)

Tags: python, seaborn

Как с помощью seaborn можно отобразить значения DataFrame в виде заштрихованной таблицы?

Ось х отображает возможные значения из дипазаона DataFrame.values для столбцов c1, c2, c3

Ось y отображает порядковый номер записи по убыванию  df.index

Для кажой строки (записи) закрашивается тот квадрат, значения которого заданы в столбцах c1, c2, c3.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


sns.set()

d = {5:{"c1":1, "c2":7, "c3":10}, 4:{"c1":1, "c2":6, "c3":8}, 3:{"c1":4, "c2":7, "c3":9}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).T


sns.relplot(data=df.T)
plt.show()

print(df)


   c1  c2  c3
5   1   7  10
4   1   6   8
3   4   7   9
```

Ожидаемый результат. Нужно чтобы и форматирование таблицы было таким же как и в примере, кроме цветов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мне стало интересно смогу ли я написать однострочник, преобразующий приведенный в вопросе `df` фрейм в такой:

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
3   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0
4   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
5   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

решение:

```
r = (df
     .stack()
     .reset_index(name="col")
     .assign(x=1)
     .pivot_table(index="level_0", columns="col", values="x")
     .reindex(range(1,11), axis=1)
     .fillna(0)
     .astype("int8")
     .rename_axis(None)
     .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

результат:

```
In [204]: r
Out[204]: 
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
3   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0
4   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
5   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

PS @stawdog уже показал как начертить требуемую таблицу.

Comment: а если усложнить задачу, и чтобы вместо 1 - прописывалось кол-во сколько раз встречалась конкретная цифра в DataFrame.Values ? Например 1 - 2 раза в приведенном примере

Comment: можешь подсказать ?

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, чтобы помочь мне нужно понимать вопрос и видеть результат;) Я думаю лучше открыть новый вопрос с примером данных и результатом

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1202551/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%b0%d1%85-dataframe-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2

Answer (score 5):

Давно я так не извращался, ну да ладно:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(rc={'figure.facecolor':'white'})

d = {5:{"c1":1, "c2":7, "c3":10}, 4:{"c1":1, "c2":6, "c3":8}, 3:{"c1":4, "c2":7, "c3":9}}

idx = max([max(val.values()) for key, val in d.items()])
cols = [5, 4, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(1, idx+1), columns=cols).T.fillna(0)

for k, v in d.items():
    for x in v.keys():
        df.loc[k, v[x]] = 1


sns.heatmap(df, cmap="Blues", cbar=False, square = True, linewidths=1, linecolor="k")
plt.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labeltop=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**

Автор вопроса попросил дополнительно закрасить ячейки "для столбцов от 1 до 5 ... бледно зеленым, а от 6 до 10 бледно желтым"

Для этого достаточно в каждую ячейку вложить соответствующее значение и построить heatmap, задав предварительно свою цветовую карту:

```
my_cmap = ["lightgreen", "darkblue", "lightyellow"]
df[df.iloc[:,5:]==0]=2
sns.heatmap(df, cmap=my_cmap, cbar=False, square = True, linewidths=1, linecolor="k")
plt.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labeltop=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете подсказать как можно фон незакаршеных ячеек для столбцов от 1 до 5 изменить  бледно зеленым, а от 6 до 10 бледно желтым ?

Comment: @YuriyTigiev я обновил ответ